# What does export do in BASH?

Tags: bash, export, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “a=b” and “export a=b” in bash](https://superuser.com/questions/18988/difference-between-ab-and-export-ab-in-bash)

It is hard to admit, but I have never really understood what exactly `export` does to an environment variable.  I know that if I don't export a variable I sometimes can't see it in child processes, but sometimes it seems like I can.  What is really going on when I say

```
export foo=5
```

and when should I not export a variable?

Comment: Here's a link to at least one other helpful question on this topic: http://superuser.com/questions/143413/linux-environment-variables/ ... since ironically this question was the first one that popped up on Google for my query on export in bash.

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/18988/difference-between-a-b-and-export-a-b-in-bash

Comment: One common use is to add `export` statements to .bashrc/.bash_profile to create persistent global variables similar to `$HOME`.

Comment: Careful, there is more to this story than initially appears. [I invite you to check my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667284/how-do-i-keep-functions-variables-local-to-my-zshrc/42081254#42081254)

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: Unix: What is the difference between source and export?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15474650/4561887)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> **ENVIRONMENT**
>
> When a program is invoked it is given an array of strings called the
>   environment.  This is a list of
>   name-value pairs, of the form
>   name=value.
>
> The shell provides several ways to manipulate the environment.  On
>   invocation, the shell  scans  its own 
>   environment and creates a parameter
>   for each name found, automatically
>   marking it for export to child
>   processes.  Executed commands inherit
>   the environment.  The `export`  and 
>   `declare  -x`  commands allow 
>   parameters  and functions to be added
>   to and deleted from the environment. 
>   If the value of a parameter in the
>   environment is modified, the new value
>   becomes part of the  environment, 
>   replacing the old.  The environment
>   inherited by any executed command
>   consists of the shell's initial
>   environment, whose values may be
>   modified in the shell, less any pairs
>   removed by the `unset`  command,  plus
>   any additions via the export and
>   `declare -x` commands.

Comment: IMHO copy-pasting an excerpt from documentation without any additional effort of explaining should not be upvoted.

Comment: That excerpt is not very clear and frankly I didn't understand what is going on.

Comment: @Artur: on the contrary: if the (excerpt from the) documentation answers a question, I'd rather not have additional explanations.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger but it seems, it doesn't. At least, I didn't get it until I read an answer by BloodPhilia which should be marked as accepted.

Comment: I believe the points Artur and Trismegistos were making is anyone can copy paste, its not always enough, clarify and provide a good answer. It's fine to copy paste some documentation or provide a link, in fact it is encouraged, but there should be some additional quality explanation. Furthermore, that explanation can easily be ignored by people like RenéNyffenegger if they do not need it, but it will be there for those who will benefit from it. We are all trying to learn and have different ways we gain understanding, this helps cover a variety of learning styles and will improve your rating.

Comment: My comment above took more time and care than the answer provided by sml and currently that answer is marked accepted by the OP. That is another point to consider.

Answer (score 207):

Exported variables get passed on to child processes, not-exported variables do not.

Comment: Can you point to any documentation to that affect.  I am looking for more information than that.  For instance, does a variable only need to be exported once, or do you need to export it after every change, etc.

Comment: You could check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/143413/linux-environment-variables/143418#143418

Comment: You can verify this by adding something to a path (say to `PYTHONPATH`) and then noting that though you can `echo $PYTHONPATH` it does not get recognized by python or bash scripts until you `export` it

Comment: This answer does not seem to be entirely true either. Bash sub-shells, for example, are to child-processes (according to `$BASHPID`) and yet you can read unexported variables from the parent shell. Simple proof: `x="y"; echo "$BASHPID: $x"; (echo "$BASHPID: $x")` 
My guess is that this is a special case which occurs when the child process is a sub-shell.

Comment: @JepZ I think the examples you've given don't apply. these are examples of either shell builtins `echo` which is not a sub-process, or shell expansions which occur in the same shell.

Answer (score 35):

When you use `export`, you are adding the variable to the environment variables list of the shell in which the export command was called and all the environment variables of a shell are passed to the child processes, thats why you can use it.

When you finish the shell its environment is destroyed, thats why the environment variables are declared and exported at login, in the .bashrc file for example