# Bash Scripting: variable value not updating in "one-liner" script

Tags: linux, terminal, script, bash-scripting

In the following "one-liner," when I change the variable `ID` value at the start of the script, the `disk` variable that follows does not seem to update. Namely, at the end of the script, the `>> /md0/DiskAnalysis/$disk.txt` portion uses the value of the `$disk` variable that was generated by a different `$ID` variable value than the one defined at the start of the script.

**Full one-liner script**

```
nohup sh -c ID="c"; disk=`udevadm info --query=all /dev/sd$ID | grep ID_SCSI_SERIAL | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`; size=`lsblk -b --output SIZE -n -d /dev/sd$ID`; size=`echo "$size / 1024 / 1024 / 10" | bc`; for i in $(seq 0 $size); do dd if=/dev/sd$ID of=/dev/shm/$ID.dd bs=10M skip=$i count=1 2>1; sha256=`sha256sum /dev/shm/$ID.dd | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`; md5=`md5sum /dev/shm/$ID.dd | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`; echo "$i,$sha256,$md5" >> /md0/DiskAnalysis/$disk.txt; done &
```

---

So, when I change `ID="b"` to `ID="c"`, the

```
disk=`udevadm info --query=all /dev/sd$ID | grep ID_SCSI_SERIAL | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
```

portion of the script does not update its value to reflect the change in the `$ID` variable value. However, If I were to execute the following by itself in terminal:

```
ID="b"; disk=`udevadm info --query=all /dev/sd$ID | grep ID_SCSI_SERIAL | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`; echo $disk
```

and

```
ID="c"; disk=`udevadm info --query=all /dev/sd$ID | grep ID_SCSI_SERIAL | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`; echo $disk
```

I get two different values for `$disk`.

What am I missing that is resulting in the `$disk` variable value not updating in the full script?

For the moment, I am assuming the change in the `$ID` value in other parts of the script (i.e. the checksums) is working correctly. However, since the `$disk` value is not updating correctly, the output isn't writing to the desired file. In fact, every time I run the script with an `$ID` value different from the original (`ID="b"`), the output from the rest of the script simple writes to the output file (i.e. `$disk`) defined by the first original `$ID`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an unquoted, unescaped `;` there.

`nohup sh -c ID="c"; whatever` runs `nohup sh -c ID="c"` first, then `whatever`.

The first command is almost a no-op. It doesn't affect the variables of the current shell, it doesn't affect expansions when `whatever` is interpreted in the current shell, it doesn't affect `whatever` in the way you want. It only creates `nohup.out` (if not yet created).

Basically you need `nohup sh -c 'ID="c"; whatever'` (add `&` if needed). Here `;` is not interpreted by the current shell. The entire single-quoted string will eventually become an option-argument passed to `sh -c`.

I haven't analyzed your specific command thoroughly enough to tell:

- if my additional level of quoting interferes with already existing quotes when applied thoughtlessly (compare [**How to single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?**](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690));
- if there is anything that shouldn't be single-quoted in the current shell;
- if the new string seen by `sh -c` contains proper quoting in the context of `sh`.

In general these are different issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'script' as written, the `sh -c` only applies to `ID="c"`, i.e. not to everything to the right of the semicolon.  This means `ID="c"` is set in a child process which is cleaned up before executing the next command.  To see this, just do `sh -c somevar="x"; echo $somevar`.

For the variable to be shared, it either needs to be exported (see [Difference between "a=b" and "export a=b" in bash](https://superuser.com/questions/18988/difference-between-a-b-and-export-a-b-in-bash)) or have the same parent process.

For example, `somevar="x"; echo $somevar` (without setting the variable in a child process) would work; or `sh -c 'somevar="x"; echo $somevar'` would also work, since the two commands are both children of `sh -c`.

Comment: Thank you. In my attempt to make "nohup" and "&" work I came across a "solution' using "sh -c". I am/was not familiar with "sh -c" but it seem to fix my "nohup"/"&" problem. I am now reading up to better understand how to properly use "export" to make everything work as desired. Even though putting it into a file and then running that script would be easier/quicker, I am in it to pick up a few new skills at this point.